# Does the cloud function timeout terminate requests sent to a database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have an external JSON db from which I'm trying to retrieve records and write files to firebase storage using cloud functions v1. I'm using async/await in a batched fashion because there are a large number of items for which I'm trying to retrieve records. Based on the cloud function logs and the files saved to firebase storage, I can see that some of the files from the first batch are saved.

However the the records from the later batches never seem to be retrieved at all. Nothing in the cloud functions logs indicate that a timeout happened (which is set to max 540 seconds).

1. If requests to fetch data were sent before the timeout but if the data retrieval takes a long time (maybe longer than the timeout), does the timeout automatically cancel those requests?
2. The current cloud function is a pub/sub function that uses a cron schedule. If the issue is that timeout is cancelling requests, will switching to cloud functions v2 help? can i use pubsub in v2 to execute on a cron schedule?

Comment: It sounds indeed like your function is getting terminated, probably because you're not telling Cloud Functions that you're still running/when you are done. I recommend reading/watching https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions. If you can't get it to work, please edit your question to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - rather than a description of what your code does.

Comment: For information, if your function reach timeout, nothing is close "nicely". It simply let in place. The request continue in database but nothing will listen the response. If you go to Cloud Functions v2, you will have a longer timeout. But the max timeout of PubSub is 600s. Therefore, use directly Cloud Scheduler to invoke your function, you will have a max timeout of 30 minutes (1800s)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and guillaume hey guys, thank you so much for your inputs. the function seems to work correctly now although the timeout is still not enough. ill move the code over to v2.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing this as a community wiki for others sake.

As mentioned by @Frank van Puffelen

> It sounds indeed like your function is getting terminated, probably because you're not telling Cloud Functions that you're still running/when you are done. I recommend reading/watching firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions. If you can't get it to work, please edit your question to show a minimal repro - rather than a description of what your code does.